# Cardinality of a connected compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, cardinals, connectedness

Is it known (in ZFC) that every connected compact Hausdorff space has cardinality at least $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$?

Comment: $X$ $T_4$ is enough. Compact is overkill, see Eric's proof.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't T$_4$ overkill too, because a Tychonoff space is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming the space has more than one point.  A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is normal, so by Urysohn's lemma given any two distinct points $x,y\in X$ there is a continuous map $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$.  If $X$ is connected, then $f$ must be surjective, and so in particular $X$ has cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$.